# Reading the schematic diagram of a power pack

Tags: power-supply, variable, schematic

We've purchased a bit old type of a power pack. It's got DC voltage manual reading bar and DC ampere manual reading bar. Assuming that it can measure the current while allowing to give a specific voltage to the circuit.

There's not much of a detail in the user manual, but there's a schematic diagram that I'm having trouble understanding.

I could use some help on how to read this:

[image: It's a bit complicated]

Comment: What do you not understand?  What do you need to know about it?

Comment: @JRE Sorry, if it hangs in the air. What I don't understand is where to start reading the schematic and where to end. I know all the circuit components as a technician but reading the big picture seems clueless to me. I thought someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe begin with a circuit that you can read. Maybe show a power supply that doesn't use a triac for voltage control - can you read that sort of simplified circuit? Nobody understands your skill level so, if you can't read a circuit of a battery and a lamp, I'm afraid this site is probably not the best to start learning on.

Comment: I can read all types of simple circuits. But, I'm having a problem with reading a huge chunk of diagrams like this. Again, where to start and where to end. The connection between parts.

Comment: What's a "manual reading bar"?

Comment: Most schematics, if properly drawn, read from left (inputs) to right (outputs).  Start at one end or the other (i.e. what do you know about the input) and work your way to the opposite end.

Comment: @SteveSh Thank you. It's also helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pot is to adjust the the AC output like a dimmer for 120 V +/-10 V output 2.5 A or **360 W**

The other outputs are transformed to a lower voltage with a filtered and unfiltered output also dimmed from the same pot suitable for 30Vdc lights 150 W max to 40Vac 200 W loads.  This can also be rectified to DC  with large caps to filter a load.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's helpful.